# An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'es5' is not set in the workspace. ng serve in angular 8 for es5

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-8

An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'es5' is not set in the workspace.

The problem starts when clients want the project to run on internet explorer 8. Luckily the new angular 8 offers differential loading.

Based on the documentation(https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading) by angular I added the es5 JSON to angular.json
Then I try to serve it using 'ng serve --configuration es5'

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "sm": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "sass"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Forex-Lottery-Front-End",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/scss/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
            ],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "es5": {
              "tsConfig": "./tsconfig-es5.app.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "sm:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "sm:build:production"
            }
          },
          "es5": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build:es5"
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "sm:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sm-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "sm:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "sm:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "sm"
}
```

The error is

An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'es5' is not set in the workspace.
See "/tmp/ng-iPbP2O/angular-errors.log" for further details.

How can i make this work?

Comment: Are you serving directly into production?

Comment: Not serving for production am serving for es5. I am serving with 'ng serve --configuration es5' ....Serving for production is with 'ng build --watch'.

Comment: Did you try to check "/tmp/ng-iPbP2O/angular-errors.log" to see if it has any information about the issue which can give any idea? If possible than also try to share the contents of that log file.

Comment: yes I did check Its the same error but if it helps...this is what it says

```
[error] Error: Configuration 'es5' is not set in the workspace.
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.getOptionsForTarget (/home/abrsh/Documents/forex/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js:72:19)
    at ArchitectTargetJobRegistry.get ```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You seem to have put the es5 configuration under the "serve" section, rather than the "configurations" section.

Also you need to change "app:build:es5" to the name of your app. So in your case "sm:build:es5".

```
"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "sm:build"
    },
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "browserTarget": "sm:build:production"
      },
      "es5": {
        "browserTarget": "sm:build:es5"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: it worked for me. thanks